# Javascript add object to constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Hello I'm trying to add a object to my Students array using a constructor,.

This would be my Student constructor.

```
var Student = function (name, address, city, state, gpa) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    console.log(name, address, city, state, gpa);
};
```

In my main js I would call and add the objects like so.

```
var Student1 = [
    new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0]),
    new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0])
];
```

But I want to add a new object later on, I thought I could just create a `Student2` and then just `Student1.push(Student2);` and then it would add the data to the `Student1 array`.  But I just get *undefined* `[object Object]` when it's displaying the `innerHTML`.

```
var Student2 = [
    new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0])
];
Student1.push(Student2);
```

Can anyone help me get this third object into the `Student1` object array?

Comment: Doing this `Student1.push(Student2);` you're pushing an array into an array. You should push it directly, like: `Student1.push(new Student(...));`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new array, just push the new Student to the Student1 array:

```
Student1.push(new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",2.5,3.1,4.0]));
```

Your current code is pushing an array containing the new student onto the Student1 array, so Student1 would look like:

```
[
    studentInstance1,
    studentInstance2,
    [
        studentInstance3
    ]
]
```

By changing to push only the new object, not an array, it now looks like:

```
[
    studentInstance1,
    studentInstance2,
    studentInstance3
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost any *Object* when converted to a *String* will display `[object Object]`. `innerHTML` takes a *String*. You need to write an extra *function* to convert a *Student* into a *String*.

```
Student.prototype.toString = function () {
    return 'Student: ' + this.name; // etc
};

({}) + '';               // "[object Object]", normal object toString
new Student('Bob') + ''; // "Student: Bob", from our toString function
```